# How to get the pronuciation of kanji in sentence if I know all the sentence pronuciation?

Tags: string, algorithm

Here the eg. 
Origin Sentence: 小さくとも健気で美しい月が
Pronuciation   : しょうさくともけなげでびしいつきが

I want to get the pronuciation of kanji,just like below

小:しょう   
健気:けなげ 
美:び      
月:き

I think [LCS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem) is one of the algorithm to get it,but it think it may fail sometimes due to the continual hiragana,so is there any better algorithm to solve this problem?

justhal is right,just let us consider the origin sentence and pronuciation sentence as strings,so what I want to do is to match the kanji with pronounciaiton.

Comment: is there even a possible computer algorithm that can solve this without the use of dictionary? How can the algorithm know that the first kanji is pronounced as three letter hiragana, and not the first two?

Comment: Is 健気:けなげ always true? so any time you see 健気, you pronounce it like けなげ? If so you could just use a set of mappings from written->pronunciation (a dictionary type structure)

Comment: @Nic: I think OP wants to get the written->pronunciation dictionary automatically from a sentence.

Comment: justhalf: You could be right, the question needs refinement. OP do you want to create the dictionary on the fly? (if so then justhalf is right) or do you have some set of mappings from written to pronunciation already? (in which case you'd just need to do a find/replace)

Comment: This is a very hard problem, since many kanji have several pronunciations depending on the context. You cannot map kanji to phonetics like that.

Comment: should be easy considering that the kanji pronunciations in the examples are partly wrong :(

Comment: @NicRobertson I dont't got a dictionary,but I want to extract the kanji Pronuncition.

Comment: That's not possible. Pronounciation depends on context,and if names are involved,you're screwed.use jdic and kanjidic for dictionary,that will give somewhat reasonable(but not necessarily correct) result in good portion of cases.

Comment: Sentence pronouncation is probably wrong in your example.  小さく is probably ちいさく and 月 could be ゲツ。

Comment: Even if you know pronunciation for the entire srntence, you can't map kanji to kanawithout kanji dictionary -you won't be able to find where one kanji ends and another starts.

Comment: @SigTerm: The question does not require that. Notice that in the example, part of the desired solution is "健気:けなげ".

Comment: @SigTerm Sorry for the wrong pronouncation,thanks for explainaiton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

//Warning: please not that I'm not japanese language expert, and still just learning it.

As far as I know, this problem cannot be reliably solved in 100% of cases with or without dictionary by computer algorithm. I suggest to give up. Or use dictionaries for non-perfect approach (with dictionary is better than without)

The most important part is that kanji is not a western letter. Kanji is a symbol that is associated with concept/idea, concepts combined together point at certain object that has a (pronounceable) word associated with it. Now, kanji have list of commonly used readings("on"/"kun"), but there are exceptions out there.

Your problem translates into: "given sequence of wildcards mixed up with letters, match every wildcard to letter sequence in given string".

Example:

猫に九生あり。-> +に++あり。

Here are the difficulties you'll run into immediately.

1. You cannot unambiguously split pronunciation into parts that are associated with certain kanji. For a simple things like 会社　（かいしゃ） you could tech your algorithm to recognize valid letter sequences that map to syllables (You can't split しゃ　into two different parts), but then you'll eventually run into word that has multiple parts or has special reading. Example: 木陰　（こかげ）　Which letter belongs to which kanji?
2. Ambiguous split of words/phrases. I.e. a particle can be part of reading.　物の怪　”もののけ”　Now, out of those two "no"s, which one belongs to which kanji?
3. Names and stylized foreign words. First two example can be solved with a dictionary. Names require special dictionary (一樹　reads as "kazuki", although　一　does not have "kazu" as its "on" or "kun" reading). Another good example is Yagami Light from Death Note that has foreign word "Light"(ライト）written as a 月　（moon/month, normally read as つき/げつ）Obviously, 月　does not read as "Light". As for foreign words, 火炎球 in "Slayers" is pronounced (by main character) as ”フャイヤーボール”　（"fireball" in english), but obviously kanji do not have those readings.

Those problems cannot be unambigously dealt with by algorithm, hence there will be no algorithm to match string. LCS and similar routines will result in incorrect splits because of #2.

To use a dictionary you can use data from [edict](http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/~jwb/edict.html) or [kanjidic](http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/~jwb/kanjidic.html), however, that won't guarantee a perfect solution. You might also want to investigate "mecab" project.

--EDIT--

> I think LCS is one of the algorithm to get it,but it think it may fail sometimes due to the continual hiragana,so is there any better algorithm to solve this problem?

You cannot solve it this way. If you only want to split phrase into words, you need to load dictionary (15+ megabytes of data) and check individual words against dictionary, plus you'll have to handle verb forms to locate word in dictionary. Simple wildcard matching will not work here.

Comment: Does mecab can get individual pronounciation of each kanji? I found it can spilt sentence and give all.which comes back to same question.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a simpler problem than LCS, because each string of hiragana in the sentence *must* appear in the pronunciation.

Let us call a string of hiragana in the sentence an "h-string".

If an h-string in the sentence matches *only one* substring in the pronunciation, then we can split the problem. For example, this:

[小**さくとも**健気で美しい月が] <=> [しょう**さくとも**けなげでびしいつきが]

becomes this:

[小] <=> [しょう]
[健気で美しい月が] <=> [けなげでびしいつきが]

In this example, this process is sufficient because there is no ambiguity; each h-string appears only once in the pronunciation. We must consider more difficult cases.

I will replace sequences of hiragana and kanji with roman characters, partly for abstraction, but mainly because I do not speak Japanese and cannot concoct real Japanese sentences as examples. The previous example becomes:

[AwBCxDyEz] <=> [swtxuyvz]

This breaks down easily:
A:s
BC:t
D:u
E:v

This process will work until we encounter a map in which all h-strings are internal and none is unique in the pronunciation:

[AyBzC] <=> [yuzyvzyzwzyx]

Now we must consider all possible matches:

[yuz**y**v**z**yzwzyx]
[yuz**y**vzy**z**wzyx]
[yuz**y**vzyzw**z**yx]
[yuzyvz**y**zw**z**yx]

In this case the algorithm must report 4 possible pronunciation of {A, B, C}.

Comment: Thanks,good abstraction,it teach me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend converting the kanji sentence to a regex as follows:

```
regex = "(*)さくとも(*)で(*)しい(*)が"
```

So you are converting all the continuous substring of kanji to (*).  Then matching that regex against the pronunciation string:

```
pronunciation = "しょうさくともけなげでびしいつきが"
```

If it produces a positive match, most regex libraries will be able to tell you "what was the text in the n-th set of parenthesis".  Just find a regex library that will let you do that; in fact, it's probably harder to find a regex library without that capability.

Comment: It's a good way,but what if there are some matches?how to deal with it?

Comment: When you pickout a regex library, learn how to use it's "backreferences" to recall part of the matched text.  It is also sometimes called "Capturing Groups".